# Android studio XML prediction not as expected

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

the following images show my problem in my Android studio. It seems like I somehow messed something up. Usually I would expect to see some predictions like "android:layout_width". Got anybody a clue what I could do to get a neat code prediction again

[image]
[image: w]

My System: 
Windows 8.1, Android studio 2.2.2, JRE 1.8.0_76

Comment: Is the problem that the common attributes like layout_width and layout_height aren't appearing first or that auto is trying to autocomplete?

Comment: common attributes like layout_width and layout_height aren't appearing is my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally,i had solved this problem by deleting .idea folder and all .iml files from the project, restarting Android Studio and rebuilding gradle did the trick. Autocomplete in XML support library is working again.

Comment: Did it once before and didn't work... did it again and .... it works ... frustrating... THX!

Answer (score 0):

type everytime attribute you want to apply instead android: .
for example if you want to apply an attribute to an Imageview
then type
**background** or other attribute like **src**  etc.

Comment: I get "No suggestions"